# How can I use go.uber.org/zap lib to print different color with different log level and append log to different file depend on the log level?

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

I started using the zap log library for my Go project. I want to print different colors to tty console based on the log level.

I find the `zap/internal/color` package can display different colors for strings, but I want to change the log level with different color.

I also want to write the log to some log files with different log level.

How to init and config the zap logger?

Comment: For how to log to different outputs based on level, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472667/how-to-log-to-stdout-or-stderr-based-on-log-level-using-uber-go-zap/68476472#68476472)

Answer (score 6):

Just met the same issue, and here are some code snippets for enable colors:

```
config := zap.NewDevelopmentConfig()
config.EncoderConfig.EncodeLevel = zapcore.CapitalColorLevelEncoder
logger, _ := config.Build()

logger.Info("Now logs should be colored")
```

reference: https://github.com/uber-go/zap/pull/307

Comment: It's discussed here as well - https://github.com/uber-go/zap/issues/648.

Comment: Seems not to work with `zap.NewProductionConfig()`